# Adding shortcut to JMenu

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts, jmenu

I want to add a shortcut to JMenu (not JMenuItem) but I don't know how... Please, help...

Comment: For future reference: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#mnemonic

Comment: am having a problem when using this on a `JMenuItem` in a `JPopupMenu` it wont work unless i press on the `JPopupMenu` and the dropdown of options appears and then while its shown it will work how can i go make the shortcut work without the need to press and show scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    JMenu actionMenu = new JMenu("Actions");
    actionMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
```

This way you can access it by pressing key <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.